# Angular ssr varnish usage

Tags: node.js, angular, performance, nginx, varnish

It working but not affect performance. Do I use it right?

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
    backend default { 
    .host = "127.0.0.1"; 
    .port = "4000"; }
```

i was add vanish port instead 4000 in nginx config

```
 location / {
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:6081;
}
```

My Angular application (google pagespeed) desktop performance is 99% but the mobile performance is 40-60%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish's out-of-the-box behavior respects HTTP caching best practices.

> **This means:**
>
> - Only cache HTTP GET & HTTP HEAD calls
> - Don't serve responses from cache when the request contains `cookie` headers
> - Don't serve responses from cache when the request contains `authorization` headers
> - Don't store responses in cache when `set-cookie` headers are present
> - Don't store responses in cache when the `cache-control` header is a *zero TTL* or when it contains the following: `no-cache`, or `no-store`, or `private`

Under all circumstances Varnish will try to serve from cache or store in cache.

This is that behavior written in VCL: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl

### Adapting to the real world

Although these caching best practices make sense, they are not realistic when you look at the *real world*. In the real world we use cookies all the time.

That's why you'll probably have to write some *VCL code* to change the behavior of the cache. In order to do so, you have to be quite familiar with the HTTP endpoints of your app, but also the parts where cookies are used.

- Parts of your app where cookie values are used on the server-side will have to be excluded from caching
- Parts of your app where cookie values aren't used will be stored in cache
- Tracking cookies that are only used at the client side will have to be stripped

### How to examine what's going on

The `varnishlog` binary will help you understand the kind of traffic that is going through Varnish and how Varnish behaves with that traffic.

I've written an in-depth blog post about this, please have a look: https://feryn.eu/blog/varnishlog-measure-varnish-cache-performance/

### Writing VCL

Once you've figured out what is causing the drop in performance, you can write VCL to mitigate. Please have a look at the docs site to learn about VCL: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/index.html

The is reference material in there, a user guide and even a tutorial.

Good luck